# Не понимаю как прикрепить внешний статический ip к Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, веб-сервер

Вообщем поставили задачу поднять сервер, локально его поднял, настроил LAMP прикрутил Webmin, дальше нужно вывести его в интернет, купили внешний статический ip, но у меня не получается его подключить

в файле /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml прописывал данные из договора (ip, шлюз, два dns)

```
network:
  ethernets:
   enp0s31f6:

 addresses: 
 -95.174.***.***/24
 gateway4: 95.174.*.*
 nameservers:
   addresses: [95.174.*.*,95.174.*.*]
```

затем sudo netplan apply

но это не помогло, возможно я сильно туплю , может нужно что в настройках роутера поменять, может кто подскажет или поделиться ссылкой

Или нужно проложить в настройках маршрут между локальным ip и внешним ?

Comment: роутер должны настроить в режим bridge, как минимум. Потом в убунту по ссылке настроить сеть https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E

Comment: А роутер у вас какую функцию сейчас выполняет? Он уже подключен к интернету? Он раздает «интернет»? Провайдер ему выдает динамический или статический ip?